# How to setup wordpress site and rails multiaccount site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, apache

I have TLD (www.example.com) and want to deploy rails 3 app (ex. app.example.com) what will have multiple accounts, each account with one subdomiain (test.example.com, support.example.com, ...).

I created tld with subdomain, changed DNS records, and everything is working. But, since there will be CNAME redirection from some other sites to specific subdomains and my default site is TLD (www.example.com) all CNAME redirects are going to main site instead of analogus subdomain!

Is there better way to integrate Rails and Wordpress? How to solve that? I'm searching for solution last two days.

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405859/how-to-config-apache-passenger-for-wordpress-and-rails

Answer (score 0):

If your ruby is in passenger mode, and your apache servicing all http queries you should be able to use the apache virtual server setup to redirect the queries for your rails apps accordingly, while leaving your Wordpress on the default web server.

I haven't done it with rails, but for Diaspora, (which is a ruby app) I have that running side by side with a Wordpress network with numerous subdomains off the TLD.  The key might be that your TLD should be example.com, not www.example.com.  (setup whichever you prefer to have wordoress on to redirect to the other)

Post some more details on your apache (or other web server environment) setup to achieve some better assistance if this doesn't help.

Yours for the cause of open source!